# Rewrite the following SQL query to turn it more efficient/improve its execution and the reasons for that

Tags: sql, database, optimization, url-rewriting, sql-tuning

Relational Schema:

```
City(cityID, nameCity, nbInhabitants)
Company(companyID, companyName, nbEmployees, cityID) cityID: FK(City)
```

Given the following statistics:
• City contains 4 000 tuples with 20 tuples per page
• Company contains 200 000 tuples with 15 tuples per page

Now rewrite the following query to improve its execution and the reasons for those benefits:

```
SELECT DISTINCT companyID
FROM City NATURAL JOIN Company
WHERE nbEmployees >= 5000
AND nameCity = 'Lisboa'
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think the `select distinct` is needed.  Why would the `companyId` be duplicated in the `company` table?  Also, I would expect the `join` to bring in only one city.

Avoid `natural join`.  It is just bugs waiting to happen.  You don't know what join keys are being used and it doesn't even use properly declared foreign key relationships.

Let me assume this is your query:

```
select c.CompanyId
from Company c join
     City ci
     on c.cityId = ci.cityId
where c.nbEmployees >= 5000 and ci.nameCity = 'Lisboa';
```

You have two approaches to optimization.  I would first suggest indexes on `Company(nbEmployees, cityId)` and `City(cityId, 'Lisboa')`.

If you have lots of companies with more than 5,000 employees and very few in Lisbon, then the alternative indexing strategy is `city(nameCity, cityId)`, `company(cityId, nbEmployees, companyId)`.

Comment: I forgot to say that cityID is PK of City and companyID is PK of Company. Does this change anything regarding your answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: Regarding your second observation: what if we suppose that companies whose number of employees is greater than let's say 10 000 are often accessed through an SQL query. Which kind of schema tuning mechanism would you use in this case to  speed it up also considereing that the number of tuples of relation Company is very big (200 000)! Thank you!

Comment: @UserFriendly . . . If those are primary keys, then `select distinct` is not needed.  I would expect the first set of indexes to be fine.  As for your second question, you might want to ask a new question.

Comment: So you would consider the query that you rewrite is the best optimization for that scenario even considering the primary keys? Thank you so much

Comment: @UserFriendly . . . The query itself is similar to your in terms of performance.  The optimization benefits come from the indexes.